# Large Modular Arithematic Exponentiation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do I calculate

- $2^{65536} \pmod{2^{31} -1}$
- $3^{256} \pmod{2^8 +1}$

Please help?

Comment: It's quite easy to do with a computer; these numbers aren't really that large.

Comment: @user61527 this from a past paper I am solving for my telecommunications exam about RSA encryptions.. I am very confused, the answer must be an integer. Help will be appreciated. I need to do this by hand ( or a handheld calculator).

Comment: @amzoti i still dont get it. Could i get a more detailed explanation , please?

Comment: I've removed the reference to RSA in the title, since it has nothing to do with the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

$(1)$

As $65536=2114\cdot31+2\pmod{31}$

$2^{65536}=2^{31\cdot2114+2}=(1+2^{31}-1)^{2114}\cdot2^2$

Now
$(1+2^{31}-1)^{2114}=1+\sum_{r=1}^{2114}\binom{2114}r(2^{31}-1)^r\equiv1\pmod{2^{31}-1}$

$(2)$

Fortunately $2^8+1=257$ is prime, so we can safely use Fermat's Little Theorem